# Linking shared library in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, makefile, dynamic-linking, shared-libraries

I would like to modify the linux kernel.

I would like to use functions from a shared library (an `.so` file) in file `kernel/panic.c`.

Unfortunately I don't know how to compile it.

When I put it in to the `Makefile` I receive the following error:

`ld: attempted static link of dynamic object`.

Is there a way to put the shared library file to the Linux kernel or do I need to recompile my library to gain an object file.

Comment: What is that shared library you want to use in kernel land? Please **edit your question** to improve and motivate it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about software development (including developing Unix kernels) are best asked on [so].

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to link shared library into kernel code ([ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared objects are a user-space thing, using [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html)...) You should consider making a [kernel module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module) (and use [modprobe(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/modprobe.8.html) to load it). Read [Loadable Kernel Module HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/).

<sup>kernel modules `*.ko` are conceptually similar to shared objects `*.so` but the [linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) mechanism is different.</sup>

BTW, you generally should avoid writing kernel code and should prefer coding application code. In other words, modifying the kernel is generally a bad idea and is frowned upon.

Also, the API available in kernel space is not the same as user space API (which extends the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) and [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) functions). For example, kernel modules (and kernel code) don't have (so cannot call) `fopen` or `fprintf` or `fork`; the kernel is a freestanding C application. Also, kernel code cannot use any floating point operation!

Userland applications are interacting with the kernel using [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (and the `libc` is using them, e.g. for `printf` or [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)). Kernel code (including kernel modules) cannot use directly syscalls (since they are *provided* by the kernel, see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)).

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (mostly about application programming) and [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (to get a broader view about OSes).