# How to build an out-of-tree linux module with an additional include path (includes external header files, librairies like yaml, boost...)

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to build an out-of-tree linux kernel that should take into account external headers files comming from pre- compiled and installed custom libraries. My linux module will use functions from a shared library via a  C-interface.
How is it possible to prevent kernel Makefile of the existence of such files?

```
    obj-m+= hello_module.o
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(OUTDIR) modules
    #additional include path
    INCLUDES :=\ 
             -I $(PROJECT_ROOT)/deps1
             -I $(PROJECT_ROOT)/deps2
             -I $(PROJECT_ROOT)/deps3
```

So how can I include this in $(MAKE) line above?
Thanks in advance,
Rgds
sahbi

Comment: `... headers files comming from already compiled and installed custom libraries.` - Linux *kernel* module **cannot be linked** with *user space* libraries. That is, you may include given header files for compilation process, but resulted module will contain *unresolved* symbols, so it couldn't be loaded into the kernel.

Comment: So what should I do instead? Actually external libraries are dynamic that's why I couldn't include once the headers in OUTDIR. I have noticed that was possible with  _VxWorks_, So my question,

Comment: How do you plan to link dynamic libraries to the kernel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking shared library in linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928255/linking-shared-library-in-linux-kernel)

Comment: example deps1 = boost, deps2 = header files template, deps3= a C-iterface using the librairy in deps2

Answer (score 0):

You cannot link user space libraries into modules.
But you can link multiple files with the following Makefile:

```
obj-m := combinedmodule.o
combinedmodule-objs := part1.o part2.o


all:
        make -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(PWD) modules
```